# Summing integrands

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have two integrals, neither of which can be solved by *Mathematica* (v. 11.3):

```
Integrate[
     Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]), 
     {x, 2, 4}]
```

and

```
Integrate[
     Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]), 
     {x, 2, 4}]
```

However, if I sum the integrands to form a single integral, *Mathematica* solves it quite trivially.

**Question**

Given two integrals, Int1 and Int2 that happen to have the same limits:  Write a function

```
myIntegrandSummer[Int1_,Int2_]:= ...
```

That will extract the integrands, sum them, then form a new single integral that uses the sum as the integrand and the limits as given by either individual integral.

Note especially:  myIntegrandSummer must *not* evaluate each integral separately.  (After all, I most want to use this function when one or both of the integrals *cannot* be performed by *Mathematica*.)

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What exactly is the input? And why can't you do as you said, just add the integrands before calling `Integrate`?  or is it you do not have access to the integrands?

Comment: You seem to be a very "sophisticated" guy who works in Silicon Valley and asks very "interesting" question. Why not to show us your "intelligence" and self-answer your very "interesting" question?

Comment: I answer questions that I can (reputation 33k), and only ask questions that I think others have insights (or know functions) I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using a replacement `Rule`

```
intSumRule =
  Inactive[Integrate][int1_, iter_] +
    Inactive[Integrate][int2_, iter_] :> Integrate[int1 + int2, iter];
```

Using the `Rule`

```
Integrate[Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]), {x, 2, 4}] +
    Integrate[
    Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]), {x, 2, 4}] /. 
  Integrate :> Inactive[Integrate] /. intSumRule

(* 2 *)
```

Comment: Yep.  Great.  Inactive was the key.  Thanks ($\checkmark$)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows

```
Integrate[   Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]), {x, 2, 
4}][[1]] + Integrate[Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]), {x, 2, 
4}][[1];
```

and then `Integrate[%, Integrate[   Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[3 + x]]), {x, 2,  4}][[2]]]` results in `2`.

Addition. In the general case

```
Activate[Integrate[Inactive[f[x]], {x, a, b}][[1]]]+Activate[Integrate[Inactive[g[x]], {x, a, b}][[1]]]
```

> `f[x]+g[x]`

and

```
Integrate[Inactive[f[x]], {x, a, b}][[2]]
```

> `{x,a,b}`

do the job for me.

Addition 2. To exract the integrand from an unevaluated integral, use

```
ToExpression[StringDrop[StringDrop["Integrate[f[x],{x,a,b}]", 10], -
StringLength[",{x,a,b}"] - 1]]
```

I leave the notation of `myIntegrandSummer[Int1_,Int2_]` on your own.

Comment: Of course I can cut and paste these two specific integrands.  I'm interested in an algorithmic way that will work with arbitrary integrals (and not try to evaluate them separately).

Comment: What do you mean by "an algorithmic way"? Why do you dislike `Integrate[f[x],{x,a,b}][[1]]` which results in `f[x]` and `Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}][[2]]` which results in `{x,a,b}`?